# Laravel API endpoints for customers and admins

Tags: laravel, rest

I am quite new to development and am building an API for a Laravel application which will be consumed by our internal React JS application.

Now considering security, both customers (external users) and staff (internal users) will log in to the application to access resources. Customers are able to do something like updating their info, and admins can also do that on behalf of the customers. However, customers are limited to what they can do, and admins can modify almost everything.

Should I separate the endpoints for these users (/api/user and /api/admin) or use permissions to determine that on the same endpoint (/api/)?

Please assist.

Comment: Check Middleware in Laravel, maybe is all you need to do what you need

Comment: You likely need a combination of policies (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization) and permissions/roles (https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction).

Comment: /api/ endpoint is better and clean, and create a midleware for checking the user role permission.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with separate routes. It's cleaner and easier to maintain in the long run; and if you think about it, you're still respecting the single responsibility principle on API level.

I would suggest using this structure.

`domain.com/api/:version/...` for user scope and `domain.com/api/:version/admin/...` for admin scope. (You can still check for permissions through a middleware and block the request if non-admin user is trying to access admin routes.)

For further reading, head over to [this page](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/).

Comment: exposing resources with `/admin` uri in this manner is not recommended and not necessarily RESTful because the ability to view a resource as an admin should not depend on the uri. authorization should be handled via request headers or `POST` body parameters.

Comment: @JeremyFiel - 
I've come across a lot of debate regarding this very situation, and there has never been a clear solution for it. It always comes down to preference and your code style. 
I personally feel like using an `/admin` uri is cleaner solution than having to check permissions and such things. I would love to hear your take on it.

Comment: From an enterprise perspective, use credentialing and not the uri. If it's something small, just use whatever and make it work for easy maintenance.

Comment: @JeremyFiel - uri also works well in enterprise. What reason would you have to say otherwise? I don't see any reason why uri is a bad choice.

Comment: it doesn't work very well because having `admin` as part of the uri resource path makes zero sense.  the permissions of a resource should not be determined by the uri. if an attacker realizes this pattern, it's an easy attack vector to change every api call to use the `/admin` to detect unprotected endpoints.  does it "work", sure, probably.  is it safe and recommended, definitely not.  But "REST" is very opinionated, and everyone will have one.